# How to effectively add Constants values into a ListBox in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Ok, say I have a Label and a ListBox in UiBinder

```
<g:Label ui:field="countryLabel" />
<g:ListBox ui:field='countryListBox' visibleItemCount='1' />
```

In MyConstants.properties file

```
country=Country
england=England
america=America
japan=Japan
....
```

in Presenter or View

```
countryLabel.setText(myConstants.country());
```

This is so easy for Label since we only need to set Text 1 time but it will be very time consuming if we do the `ListBox`

```
countryListBox.addItem(myConstants.england());
countryListBox.addItem(myConstants.america());
etc... there will have 200 countries out there
```

So my question is, is there any quicker way to effectively add Constants values into a ListBox in GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution, but not sure I am doing correctly:

In MyConstants.properties file

```
countryArray=England, America, Japan,...
```

in MyConstants.java

```
String[] countryArray();
```

in Presenter or View

```
for(String s : myConstants.countryArray()){
   countryListBox.addItem(s);
}
```